# Crystal reports already installed,but access web page need windows security?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, windows-security

It's anyone can help?This problem borning me two days.
when i published website on IIS,and I already installed Crystal reports(CRRedist2005_X64),but when i want to check my report that time,dispaly need me keyin windows account and password,anyone worked about this?

Windows server 2008 R
64Bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open sql server>reporting services configuration manager > change report virtual directory name
or try stop reporting services

Already fixed

Answer (score 0):

If you enable anonymous authentication in your config file you won't need to enter a username or password to access public areas of your site.

Comment: Hi,thanks your reply.About config file,i copy from can work server.Means current I want to move server(A) to other server(B),but B cannot work,A can.
And could you write example for me about anonymous authentication?